# Scrapy ignoring robots.txt and not parsing page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl [ACRIS](https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/PartyName) in a similar way to what I found in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786934/2397875) here (look at the UPDATE answer). I slightly altered the code in order to remove deprecated stuff.

At first I had problems with `robots.txt` restricting me, so I found I can set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` in settings.py and indeed it seems to ignore it but for some reason the spider isn't getting to the `parse` method anymore.

This is my spider

```
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
import logging

class AcrisItem(Item):
    borough = Field()
    block = Field()


class AcrisSpider(Spider):
    name = "acris"
    allowed_domains = ["a836-acris.nyc.gov"]
    start_urls = ['https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/PartyName']

    def start_requests(self):
        return [(Request(url, meta={'dont_redirect': True}, callback=self.parse)) for url in self.start_urls]

    def parse(self, response):
        form_token = response.selector.xpath('//input[@name="__RequestVerificationToken"]/@value').extract_first()

        logging.debug('THE FORM TOKEN IS: %s\n\n' % form_token)

        formdata = {
            "__RequestVerificationToken": form_token,
            "hid_last": "SMITH",
            "hid_first": "JOHN",
            "hid_ml": "",
            "hid_suffix": "",
            "hid_business": "",
            "hid_selectdate": "To Current Date",
            "hid_datefromm": "",
            "hid_datefromd": "",
            "hid_datefromy": "",
            "hid_datetom": "",
            "hid_datetod": "",
            "hid_datetoy": "",
            "hid_partype": "",
            "hid_borough": "All Boroughs/Counties",
            "hid_doctype": "All Document Classes",
            "hid_max_rows": "10",
            "hid_page": "1",
            "hid_partype_name": "All Parties",
            "hid_doctype_name": "All Document Classes",
            "hid_borough_name": "All Boroughs/Counties",
            "hid_ReqID": "",
            "hid_SearchType": "PARTYNAME",
            "hid_ISIntranet": "N",
            "hid_sort": ""
        }

        if form_token:
            yield FormRequest(url="https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/PartyNameResult",
                              method="POST",
                              formdata=formdata,
                              meta={'dont_redirect': True},
                              callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        rows = response.selector.xpath('//form[@name="DATA"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr')

        for row in rows:
            item = AcrisItem()

            borough = row.xpath('.//td[3]/div/font/text()').extract_first()
            block = row.xpath('.//td[4]/div/font/text()').extract_first()

            if borough and block:
                item['borough'] = borough
                item['block'] = block

                yield item
```

And this is the output (minus the init messages)

```
2017-01-04 17:06:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-04 17:06:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-04 17:06:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-04 17:06:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/PartyName> (referer: None)
2017-01-04 17:06:41 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <301 https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/PartyName>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-01-04 17:06:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-04 17:06:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 243,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 414,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 15, 6, 41, 791647),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 15, 6, 12, 467659)}
2017-01-04 17:06:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Your `'dont_redirect': True` meta settings is blocking redirects, is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are forbidding direct redirect on the `start_requests`. So the `301` should reach the `parse` method, unfortunately you haven't allowed this response status code to pass.

Allow it with the attribute:

```
class AcrisSpider(Spider):
    ...
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]
    ...
```

or passing the `handle_httpstatus_all=True` meta parameter inside the request like:

```
return [(Request(url, meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_all':True}, callback=self.parse)) for url in self.start_urls]
```

Comment: Ok now `parse` is being called but it seems that the response isn't the intended page. I scraped the title and it says "Document Moved" instead of "ACRIS Search By Party Name". Any idea what's going on?

Comment: aren't you crawling a `301` status? that is a redirect. If you didn't want to handle the redirect, why did you add the `dont_redirect` meta parameter? Also visiting the site shows that access to ACRIS is denied

Comment: I do want to handle it but for some reason I don't get the doc I think i should get. Visiting https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/PartyName in the browser gets me the desired doc but with scrapy It seems I'm getting something else and I don't quite get why. I need the verification code from the first page to go to the next one but as I said I'm getting 'Document Moved'

Comment: Although it not yet working for me you did answer the original question so I must accept it. Thanks.